# How to add text over the image in bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am noob in bootstrap and making one simple responsive web design. I had given the bootstrap container the image now i want to add text over the images, so i can add more text and images on that container. I tried on google but didn't find the exact answer. Please help

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-8 col-centered">
            <div class="maintxt">
                <img src="background.png" class="img-responsive">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and here is the image, what i want - https://i.stack.imgur.com/4PY2S.jpg

Comment: Isherwood's answer is great. BTW, col-xs-12 is not necessary. It's very rare that you use col-X-12, it will automatically be full width below the  column classes you used, so under col-sm that will be full width. Col-X-12 is used when you are nesting or in between so col-sm-6 col-md-12 and col-lg-8 for example

Answer (score 13):

I'd be inclined to put the image in place as a background:

```
.maintxt {
    background-image: url(images/background.png);
    background-size: cover;
}

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-8 col-centered">
            <div class="maintxt">
                My great text.
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

If that doesn't work, you'll need to use relative and absolute positioning:

```
.maintxt {position: relative;}
.maintxt > img, .overlay-text {position: absolute;}

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-8 col-centered">
            <div class="maintxt">
                <img src="background.png" class="img-responsive">
                <span class="overlay-text">My super text.</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/an38qf0y/1/)

Answer (score 5):

I can say after your `<img>` tag add the `<p class="carousel-caption">Some text here </p>`
Your text will appear on your image !. 
The idea is that the carousel-caption uses absolute positioning so that `<p>` tag gets taken out of normal HTML flow and then using z-index:10 the `<p>` tag gets displayed over parent element ! . And all the heavy lifting for placing text over image is taken care by `class="carousel-caption"` . (Now if you wish to align text perfectly at center add custom `top:xyz%` according to your needs )
 
**Long story , short** . Add `class=carousel-caption` to the HTML tag which contains your text which needs to be positioned over your image !.(And then if you wish add custom css `top:xyz%` to your .carousel-caption class in css stylesheet to make it align vertically at middle.)

Comment: this works in case of single image but when I try to create a dynamic gallery it puts all the texts over the first image

Comment: I didn't get what are you trying to say exactly, Are you saying that the images are loaded say from array of URLs (i.e. say 10 different images) and then you're using only one <p class=carousel-caption> over it ?

Comment: Actually, I am using ejs to dynamically populate images, so it does not work in that case